# $ \int \frac{1+\sin 4x}{(\sin x -\cos x) \cdot \cos x}\, dx$ by substitution

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have to solve this integral $$ \int \frac{1+\sin 4x}{(\sin x -\cos x) \cdot \cos x}\, dx$$
It seems that the most convenient way to operate is doing the substitution $ \tan x = t$.
Then after some passages the integral becomes:
$$  \int \frac{t^4-4t^3+2t^2+4t+1}{(t-1)(t^2+1)^2}\, dx  $$

Now I'm trying the coefficient A,B,C,D,E and F such as:

$$\frac{t^4-4t^3+2t^2+4t+1}{(t-1)(t^2+1)^2} = \frac{A}{t-1}+\frac{2B(t-1)+C}{t^2+1}+ \frac {d}{dx} \frac{D(t-1)^2+E(t-1)+F}{(t-1)(t^2+1)}$$

Perhaps I made mistakes in this last passage because I find some coefficients that don't lead to the result suggested by the book.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the expression differ in terms of the integration constant?

Comment: my result is quite different from the solution of the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{{{t}^{4}}-4 {{t}^{3}}+2 {{t}^{2}}+4 t+1}{\left( t-1\right)  {{\left( {{t}^{2}}+1\right) }^{2}}}=-\frac{4}{{{t}^{2}}+1}+\frac{4-4 t}{{{\left( {{t}^{2}}+1\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{1}{t-1}$$

Details:
$$\frac{{{t}^{4}}-4 {{t}^{3}}+2 {{t}^{2}}+4 t+1}{\left( t-1\right)  {{\left( {{t}^{2}}+1\right) }^{2}}}=\frac{B t+C}{{{t}^{2}}+1}+\frac{D t+E}{{{\left( {{t}^{2}}+1\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{A}{t-1}$$

$$\frac{{{t}^{4}}-4 {{t}^{3}}+2 {{t}^{2}}+4 t+1}{{{t}^{5}}-{{t}^{4}}+2 {{t}^{3}}-2 {{t}^{2}}+t-1}=\frac{\left( B+A\right)  {{t}^{4}}+\left( C-B\right)  {{t}^{3}}+\left( D-C+B+2 A\right)  {{t}^{2}}+\left( E-D+C-B\right)  t-E-C+A}{{{t}^{5}}-{{t}^{4}}+2 {{t}^{3}}-2 {{t}^{2}}+t-1}$$

$$\left( B+A\right)  {{t}^{4}}+\left( C-B\right)  {{t}^{3}}+\left( D-C+B+2 A\right)  {{t}^{2}}+\left( E-D+C-B\right)  t-E-C+A={{t}^{4}}-4 {{t}^{3}}+2 {{t}^{2}}+4 t+1$$
Solve system
$$-E-C+A=1\operatorname{,}E-D+C-B=4\operatorname{,}D-C+B+2 A=2\operatorname{,}C-B=-4\operatorname{,}B+A=1$$
We get
$$D=-4\operatorname{,}B=0\operatorname{,}E=4\operatorname{,}C=-4\operatorname{,}A=1$$

Comment: great but how did you find this coefficient?

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

$$2(\sin x-\cos x)\cos x =\sin2x-2\cos^2x =\sin2x-\cos2x+1=y\text{(say)}$$

Now $1+\sin4x=2-(\cos2x-\sin2x)^2=2-(y-1)^2=?$

Again, $\dfrac{2-(y-1)^2}y=-y+2+\dfrac1y$

Finally $\dfrac1y=\dfrac1{(\sin x-\cos x)\cos x}=\dfrac{\sec^2x}{\tan x-1}$

Should I leave it here ?

Comment: can you show me how to solve this integral just doing the substitution $t=\tan x$ seen that it's the only type of substitution i've learned so far?

Comment: @Anne, That is required for the last part only, right? Why shall we substitute  for $$\int\sin2x\ dx,\int\cos2x\ dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $t=2x+\frac\pi4$ as shown below

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1+\sin 4x}{(\sin x -\cos x) \cos x}\, dx\\
=& \int \frac{2(\sin2x +\cos 2x )^2}{\sin2x-\cos2x-1}dx
=-\int \frac{2\sin^2t}{1+\sqrt2\cos t}dx\\
=& \int \left(- 1+\sqrt2\cos t -\frac1{1+\sqrt2\cos t}\right)dt\\
= &-t + \sqrt2\sin t - \ln| \frac{\sqrt2+1+\tan\frac t2}{\sqrt2+1-\tan\frac t2}|  +C\\
\end{align}